Build Rviz for ROS2 foxy arm64 version fails, lots of ament_add_gmock errors
I build rviz of version 8.2.8 for ros2 arm64 versino in a docker with image ros:foxy --platform=arm64 (from https://discourse.ros.org/t/announcing-ros-foxy-docker-images-availability/14511), and after I fix some errors due to lack of third-party libraries, I am stucked in the following errors:
root@9e1882f604d9:/home/michael/work/src/rviz2# colcon build --merge-install
Starting >>> rviz_assimp_vendor
Starting >>> rviz_ogre_vendor
Finished <<< rviz_assimp_vendor [2.63s]
Finished <<< rviz_ogre_vendor [2.69s]
Starting >>> rviz_rendering
--- stderr: rviz_rendering
CMake Error at /opt/ros/foxy/share/ament_cmake_gmock/cmake/ament_add_gmock.cmake:69 (add_executable):
Target "point_cloud_test_target" links to target
"rviz_ogre_vendor::OgreOverlay" but the target was not found. Perhaps a
find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target
is missing?
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/opt/ros/foxy/share/ament_cmake_gmock/cmake/ament_add_gmock.cmake:52 (_ament_add_gmock)
CMakeLists.txt:186 (ament_add_gmock)

CMake Error at /opt/ros/foxy/share/ament_cmake_gmock/cmake/ament_add_gmock.cmake:69 (add_executable):
Target "wrench_visual_test_target" links to target
"rviz_ogre_vendor::OgreOverlay" but the target was not found. Perhaps a
find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target
is missing?
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/opt/ros/foxy/share/ament_cmake_gmock/cmake/ament_add_gmock.cmake:52 (_ament_add_gmock)
CMakeLists.txt:271 (ament_add_gmock)

CMake Error at /opt/ros/foxy/share/ament_cmake_gmock/cmake/ament_add_gmock.cmake:69 (add_executable):
Target "string_helper_test" links to target "rviz_ogre_vendor::OgreOverlay"
but the target was not found. Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for
an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/opt/ros/foxy/share/ament_cmake_gmock/cmake/ament_add_gmock.cmake:52 (_ament_add_gmock)
CMakeLists.txt:181 (ament_add_gmock)

CMake Error at /opt/ros/foxy/share/ament_cmake_gmock/cmake/ament_add_gmock.cmake:69 (add_executable):
Target "point_cloud_renderable_test_target" links to target
"rviz_ogre_vendor::OgreOverlay" but the target was not found. Perhaps a
find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target
is missing?
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/opt/ros/foxy/share/ament_cmake_gmock/cmake/ament_add_gmock.cmake:52 (_ament_add_gmock)
CMakeLists.txt:198 (ament_add_gmock)

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:171 (add_library):
Target "rviz_rendering_test_utils" links to target
"rviz_ogre_vendor::OgreOverlay" but the target was not found. Perhaps a
find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target
is missing?

CMake Error at /opt/ros/foxy/share/ament_cmake_gmock/cmake/ament_add_gmock.cmake:69 (add_executable):
Target "billboard_line_test_target" links to target
"rviz_ogre_vendor::OgreOverlay" but the target was not found. Perhaps a
find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target
is missing?
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/opt/ros/foxy/share/ament_cmake_gmock/cmake/ament_add_gmock.cmake:52 (_ament_add_gmock)
CMakeLists.txt:210 (ament_add_gmock)

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:67 (add_library):
Target "rviz_rendering" links to target "rviz_ogre_vendor::OgreOverlay" but
the target was not found. Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?

CMake Error at /opt/ros/foxy/share/ament_cmake_gmock/cmake/ament_add_gmock.cmake:69 (add_executable):
Target "covariance_visual_test_target" links to target
"rviz_ogre_vendor::OgreOverlay" but the target was not found. Perhaps a
find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target
is missing?
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/opt/ros/foxy/share/ament_cmake_gmock/cmake/ament_add_gmock.cmake:52 (_ament_add_gmock)
CMakeLists.txt:222 (ament_add_gmock)

CMake Error at /opt/ros/foxy/share/ament_cmake_gmock/cmake/ament_add_gmock.cmake:69 (add_executable):
Target "grid_test_target" links to target "rviz_ogre_vendor::OgreOverlay"
but the target was not found. Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for
an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/opt/ros/foxy/share/ament_cmake_gmock/cmake/ament_add_gmock.cmake:52 (_ament_add_gmock)
CMakeLists.txt:234 (ament_add_gmock)

CMake Error at /opt/ros/foxy/share/ament_cmake_gmock/cmake/ament_add_gmock.cmake:69 (add_executable):
Target "movable_text_test_target" links to target
"rviz_ogre_vendor::OgreOverlay" but the target was not found. Perhaps a
find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target
is missing?
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/opt/ros/foxy/share/ament_cmake_gmock/cmake/ament_add_gmock.cmake:52 (_ament_add_gmock)
CMakeLists.txt:246 (ament_add_gmock)

CMake Error at /opt/ros/foxy/share/ament_cmake_gmock/cmake/ament_add_gmock.cmake:69 (add_executable):
Target "movable_text_test_target" links to target
"rviz_ogre_vendor::OgreOverlay" but the target was not found. Perhaps a
find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target
is missing?
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/opt/ros/foxy/share/ament_cmake_gmock/cmake/ament_add_gmock.cmake:52 (_ament_add_gmock)
CMakeLists.txt:246 (ament_add_gmock)

CMake Error at /opt/ros/foxy/share/ament_cmake_gmock/cmake/ament_add_gmock.cmake:69 (add_executable):
Target "line_test_target" links to target "rviz_ogre_vendor::OgreOverlay"
but the target was not found. Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for
an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/opt/ros/foxy/share/ament_cmake_gmock/cmake/ament_add_gmock.cmake:52 (_ament_add_gmock)
CMakeLists.txt:259 (ament_add_gmock)

CMake Generate step failed. Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.

Failed <<< rviz_rendering [3.88s, exited with code 1]

Summary: 2 packages finished [7.82s]
1 package failed: rviz_rendering
1 package had stderr output: rviz_rendering
5 packages not processed

I installed may packages of ros-ament-*, but can't fix them.
root@9e1882f604d9:/home/michael/work/src/rviz2# apt list ros-*-ament* | grep installed
ros-foxy-ament-cmake-auto/focal,now 0.9.12-1focal.20230527.034115 arm64 [installed,automatic]
ros-foxy-ament-cmake-copyright/focal,now 0.9.8-1focal.20230527.040734 arm64 [installed,automatic]
ros-foxy-ament-cmake-core/focal,now 0.9.12-1focal.20230527.032629 arm64 [installed,automatic]
ros-foxy-ament-cmake-cppcheck/focal,now 0.9.8-1focal.20230527.041005 arm64 [installed,automatic]
ros-foxy-ament-cmake-cpplint/focal,now 0.9.8-1focal.20230527.044538 arm64 [installed,automatic]
ros-foxy-ament-cmake-export-definitions/focal,now 0.9.12-1focal.20230527.033821 arm64 [installed,automatic]
ros-foxy-ament-cmake-export-dependencies/focal,now 0.9.12-1focal.20230527.033904 arm64 [installed,automatic]
ros-foxy-ament-cmake-export-include-directories/focal,now 0.9.12-1focal.20230527.033816 arm64 [installed,automatic]
ros-foxy-ament-cmake-export-interfaces/focal,now 0.9.12-1focal.20230527.033600 arm64 [installed,automatic]
ros-foxy-ament-cmake-export-libraries/focal,now 0.9.12-1focal.20230527.033536 arm64 [installed,automatic]
ros-foxy-ament-cmake-export-link-flags/focal,now 0.9.12-1focal.20230527.033819 arm64 [installed,automatic]
ros-foxy-ament-cmake-export-targets/focal,now 0.9.12-1focal.20230527.033602 arm64 [installed,automatic]
ros-foxy-ament-cmake-flake8/focal,now 0.9.8-1focal.20230527.041059 arm64 [installed,automatic]
ros-foxy-ament-cmake-gmock/focal,now 0.9.12-1focal.20230527.040917 arm64 [installed,automatic]
ros-foxy-ament-cmake-gtest/focal,now 0.9.12-1focal.20230527.040644 arm64 [installed,automatic]
ros-foxy-ament-cmake-include-directories/focal,now 0.9.12-1focal.20230527.033849 arm64 [installed,automatic]
ros-foxy-ament-cmake-libraries/focal,now 0.9.12-1focal.20230527.033841 arm64 [installed,automatic]
ros-foxy-ament-cmake-lint-cmake/focal,now 0.9.8-1focal.20230527.040626 arm64 [installed,automatic]
ros-foxy-ament-cmake-pep257/focal,now 0.9.8-1focal.20230527.041105 arm64 [installed,automatic]
ros-foxy-ament-cmake-pytest/focal,now 0.9.12-1focal.20230527.043854 arm64 [installed,automatic]
ros-foxy-ament-cmake-python/focal,now 0.9.12-1focal.20230527.033817 arm64 [installed,automatic]
ros-foxy-ament-cmake-ros/focal,now 0.9.2-1focal.20230527.045739 arm64 [installed,automatic]
ros-foxy-ament-cmake-target-dependencies/focal,now 0.9.12-1focal.20230527.033914 arm64 [installed,automatic]
ros-foxy-ament-cmake-test/focal,now 0.9.12-1focal.20230527.033843 arm64 [installed,automatic]
ros-foxy-ament-cmake-uncrustify/focal,now 0.9.8-1focal.20230527.040848 arm64 [installed,automatic]
ros-foxy-ament-cmake-version/focal,now 0.9.12-1focal.20230527.033844 arm64 [installed,automatic]
ros-foxy-ament-cmake-xmllint/focal,now 0.9.8-1focal.20230527.041123 arm64 [installed,automatic]
ros-foxy-ament-cmake/focal,now 0.9.12-1focal.20230527.034003 arm64 [installed,automatic]
ros-foxy-ament-copyright/focal,now 0.9.8-1focal.20230527.040308 arm64 [installed,automatic]
ros-foxy-ament-cppcheck/focal,now 0.9.8-1focal.20230527.033907 arm64 [installed,automatic]
ros-foxy-ament-cpplint/focal,now 0.9.8-1focal.20230527.044409 arm64 [installed,automatic]
ros-foxy-ament-flake8/focal,now 0.9.8-1focal.20230527.034018 arm64 [installed,automatic]
ros-foxy-ament-index-cpp/focal,now 1.1.0-1focal.20230527.044824 arm64 [installed,automatic]
ros-foxy-ament-index-python/focal,now 1.1.0-1focal.20230527.040511 arm64 [installed,automatic]
ros-foxy-ament-lint-auto/focal,now 0.9.8-1focal.20230527.034012 arm64 [installed,automatic]
ros-foxy-ament-lint-cmake/focal,now 0.9.8-1focal.20230527.040514 arm64 [installed,automatic]
ros-foxy-ament-lint-common/focal,now 0.9.8-1focal.20230527.044618 arm64 [installed,automatic]
ros-foxy-ament-lint/focal,now 0.9.8-1focal.20230527.033909 arm64 [installed,automatic]
ros-foxy-ament-package/focal,now 0.9.5-1focal.20210422.231141 arm64 [installed,automatic]
ros-foxy-ament-pep257/focal,now 0.9.8-1focal.20230527.040159 arm64 [installed,automatic]
ros-foxy-ament-uncrustify/focal,now 0.9.8-1focal.20230527.034242 arm64 [installed,automatic]
ros-foxy-ament-xmllint/focal,now 0.9.8-1focal.20230527.040536 arm64 [installed,automatic]
ros-foxy-launch-testing-ament-cmake/focal,now 0.10.10-1focal.20230527.045532 arm64 [installed,automatic]

How to fix it?
Thanks.

I finally avoided this error by using the following command:
colcon build --merge-install --cmake-args -DBUILD_TESTING=0

